# PHP problem with start simultaneous scripts

Tags: php, session

I'd like to use ajax to start asynchronously one php script. I try to use another ajax request to get information about progress of it... but.
I can't. Second request will wait for the first one. Is it cause by the nature of PHP? I guess that it can be also caused by handling session in both of scripts - Am I right?

//edit

Due to asks - I use opera web browser. I will check also firefox with firebug as you recommended to me.

Comment: not at all. it might be caused by implementation of multithreading in your browser. by the way, which one do you use? did you try different browsers? how do they behave?

Comment: check that your ajax requests are asynchronous, async keyword in jQuery

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created an xhtml-request it can be that you need another one. For this usecase there are some libraries avalaible.